# How to repeat n elements of a list in a function in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop

So, consider the following:

```
data <- list(list(1, 2, 3, 4), list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), list(1, 2, 3, 4), list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Now, I want a for loop to get n elements of "data" and execute a function on their elements. For example, if n=3, then:

```
for(i in 1:length(data)) {
  myfunc(data[[1]][[i]], data[[2]][[i]], data[[3]][[i]])
}
```

If n=2, then:

```
for(i in 1:length(data)) {
  myfunc(data[[1]][[i]], data[[2]][[i]])
}
```

And if n=1, then:

```
for(i in 1:length(data)) {
  myfunc(data[[1]][[i]])
}
```

So basically, I want to know how given an "n", we can automate this process.

Comment: Is there a strict requirement for a `for` loop? Also, I'm inferring your use of `function(data[1][i])` is that you have an arbitrary function that happens to be named here the same as the R reserved word `function`. I cannot define or even _use_ such a function named `"function"` without backticks, as in `\`function\` <- function(z) 1` and then `\`function\`(9)`, since it is a parsing error. For clarity, in case others have questions, it might be useful to use a different token in your expressions such as `myfun(data[1][i])`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the tip. I changed the "function" name to "myfunc". I don't strictly need a for loop for the value of "n".

Comment: Okay, thank you. Since you're iterating over `1:length(data)`, it seems to me that `data[1][i]` is only safe so long as `length(data)` and `length(data[[1]])` are identical, otherwise you may be mis-indexing. Also ... there's the whole `[`-vs-`[[` issue here, `data[1][i]` will always fail when `i > 1`, since `data[1]` (and `data[2]`) will always return a `list` of length-1, regardless of the value of `i`. Perhaps you mean `data[[2]][i]`?

Comment: @r2evans yeah I think you are correct. Let me make some alterations to the code so it explains my problem better. What I basically mean here is that how can I get n elements of a list and put them in a function as separate objects?

Comment: It might help to have a more concrete function? Perhaps as simple as `myfun <- function(...) paste(..., collapse=";")`?

Comment: @r2evans well maybe, but I'm not sure how to write that concrete function. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your indexing is still potentially mixed, are you sure you should not be iterating over `1:length(data[[1]])`?

Comment: @r2evans Yeah i'm pretty sure. Because I actually want to make a function with this code, so given any list (data) of any length, it can execute myfunc on the 1:length(data) elements of n elements of that list.

Comment: Okay. I've posted my thoughts as an answer, but lacking clarity on the indexing nor what you expect out of it (your `for` loop is returning nothing, so all return values are ignored/lost) I think I'm out for now. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can resolve this with some indirect execution using `do.call` and element-wise iteration using `Map`.

I'll demonstrate using a simple function that will simply collapse its `n`-arguments into `;`-delimited strings.

```r
myfun <- function(...) paste(..., sep=";")
```

Demo:

```r
n <- 3
do.call(Map, c(list(f = myfun), data[seq_len(n)]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "1;4;7"   # result of `myfun(data[[1]][1], data[[2]][1], data[[3]][1])`
# [[2]]
# [1] "2;5;8"   # result of `myfun(data[[1]][2], data[[2]][2], data[[3]][2])`
# [[3]]
# [1] "3;6;9"   # result of `myfun(data[[1]][3], data[[2]][3], data[[3]][3])`
n <- 2
do.call(Map, c(list(f = myfun), data[seq_len(n)]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "1;4"     # result of `myfun(data[[1]][1], data[[2]][1])`
# [[2]]
# [1] "2;5"     # result of `myfun(data[[1]][2], data[[2]][2])`
# [[3]]
# [1] "3;6"     # result of `myfun(data[[1]][3], data[[2]][3])`
n <- 1
do.call(Map, c(list(f = myfun), data[seq_len(n)]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "1"       # result of `myfun(data[[1]][1])`
# [[2]]
# [1] "2"       # result of `myfun(data[[1]][2])`
# [[3]]
# [1] "3"       # result of `myfun(data[[1]][3])`
```

Comment: Yes! I think a combination of do.call, Map, and seq_len were what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, the `seq_len` is similar to `1:n`; its advantage is when `n` is determined programmatically and you cannot guarantee `n > 0` (that is, `seq_len(2)` and `1:2` are the same, but `seq_len(0)` and `1:0` are very different). The use of `seq_len` is merely a defensive technique against programmatic sequencing.